# Search for elements of array in a text file

Tags: c#, .net

I have two text files (txt1 and txt2). Each file contain thousands words. I am reading txt1 and split it into an array, and I am reading the txt2. I would count the element of the array that appear in txt2. When I am printing the value of `c`, I have to get `c=5` instead of `c=2`.

Here is the section of relevant code:

```
string st=File.ReadAllLines("path");
int c = 0;

string[] split = st.Split(' ');

foreach (string s in split)
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("path"))
    {
        if (line.Contains(s))
        {
            c++; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code misses duplicates in the same line.

Comment: Please post the contents of text file.

Comment: If you don't show us the contents of the file peple don't know why c should be 5. There doesn't seem to be something wrong with the code, except that you can change the order of the for-loop so that you only load the file once

Comment: On a side note: I'd invert the two foreach(), because you read the file for every s in split. Instead you should load the file once and then scan for every s in split. That's way more efficient.

Comment: line.Contains, you are sure to use it?  if (s) contains for example "abc" and  line contains "abcdefg"  varabile (c) are incrased. i think you need more solution to fix it. Maybe post file contents on pastebin

Comment: If any provided answers have helped, etiquette is to mark this as "the answer" and probably upvote its usefulness. 
This prevents this question coming up under "show unanswered questions" in SOF and also gives some more reputation to the person who helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not know why you got c=5 instead of c=2 without looking at the files (please include them), however it seems like you are assuming that the first text contains only one row, since you use ReadAllLines, but assigning the result to a string and not array of strings. It may be you got that result because you have more words in other line in txt1. 
If it is the case you should unite the words of each line in your "split" variable:

```
string[] st=File.ReadAllLines("path");
int c = 0;

List<string> words = new List<string>();

foeach (string s in st){
    string[] split = s.Split(' ');
    foreach(string word in split){
        words.add(word);
    }
}

foreach (string s in words)
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("path"))
    {
        if (line.Contains(s))
        {
            c++; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You looped through all lines of the second text file, but you only took the first line of the first text file. To take all lines, your need to loop through them like you did with the second file:

```
int c = 0;
foreach (string st in File.ReadAllLines("path")) {
    string[] split = st.Split(' ');
    foreach (string s in split) {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("path")) {
            if (line.Contains(s)) {
                c++; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although, this is a very inefficient way of doing it. You're reading the second file again and again for every word in the first file. Consider reading the second file only once and then using the list variable in the loop:

```
int c = 0;
var st1 = File.ReadAllLines("path"); //the path to the first file
var st2 = File.ReadAllLines("path"); //the path to the second file

foreach (string line1 in st1) {
    foreach (string s in line1.Split(' ')) {
        foreach (string line2 in st2) {
            if (line2.Contains(s)) {
                c++; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having the text file I can only assume here. The most obvious thing that can lead to miscounting is case sensitivity. `Eg "Alex" != "alex"` they are not the same. 
Once that both text files have been imported - they a should all be lower or upper case.

I do prefer reading the content of a file using File.ReadAllText and store it in a List.

My approach uses LINQ and returns an Anonymous type.

```
        var file1 = File.ReadAllText(@"path\file1.txt").Split(' ').Select(x=> x.ToLower()).ToList();
        var file2 = File.ReadAllText(@"path\file2.txt").Split(' ').Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToList();

        var result = file1.Select(x => new { Word = x, Occurance = file2.Count(c => c == x) }).ToList();
```